# HTTP Status 404 - /FirstSpringMVCProject/WEB-INFHelloPage/.jsp

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to learn the spring mvc framework but when I try to run the code underneat on the server, I am not getting anything rendered also only the error in the screen shoot. But I have noticed that the url has the following `WEB-INFHelloPage/.jsp` in the 404 error. Is that normal (also wihout backslash between `WEB-INF/HelloPage.jsp`)? And Why am I not getting something as:

**First Spring MVC Application Demo**

Hi user, welcome to the first Spring MVC Application

rendered?

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>FirstSpringMVCProject</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

**HelloController class:**

```
package com.stack;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

public class HelloController extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        ModelAndView modelandview = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
        modelandview.addObject("welcomeMessage", "Hi User, welcome to the first Spring MVC Application");
        return modelandview;
    }

}
```

**spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="HandlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />

    <bean name="/welcome.html" class="com.stack.HelloController" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>


    </bean>


</beans>
```

**HelloPage.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<!-- <title>Insert title here</title> -->
</head>

<h1> First Spring MVC Application Demo </h1>

<h2>${welcomeMessage}</h2>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**screen shoot**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is explicit about that: you forgot the ending `/` in prefix property. It should be:

```
...
<property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
...
```

But with a decent version of Spring MVC, you have no reason to use an explicit `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` nor derive you controller class from `AbstractController`. Those were for Spring 2.0, but since 3.1 `RequestMapping` annotated methods are both more powerful and simpler to use.